# What's the difference between desktop and mobile IE

Tags: mobile, internet-explorer, windows, desktop

In a company I'm working we are planning to get some devices in order to test our software on it. We are doing web app, so I need to know Is there a big difference between **Windows 8 IE**, **Windows phone  IE**  and **Windows RT IE**
In other words should we test on all three devices or testing on desktop IE should be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Internet Explorer found on Windows Phone uses the same engine as the desktop version of IE. I think the only difference between them is the viewport/screen sizes that they'll be viewed on.

I think really you can test mobile sites on the desktop version of IE the same way you would with Safari, just resize the screen.

Comment: you are correct sir: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_(layout_engine)

Comment: @albert Thx guys!
But seems JavaScript interpreter not included in Trident, so it may differ from platform to platform..

Comment: huh....can you be more specific? i'm confused.

Comment: IE has the same Chakra JavaScript engine on both Windows and Windows Phone. There are a few 'edge' differences & bugs that don't affect that many sites. For the most part Mick is correct you can use IE 10 and resize for about a 99.5% coverage. Remember till Windows Phone is updated to WP 8.1 the browser is IE 10, so you should open the F12 tools and use the window phone compatibility mode to get a more accurate test.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/testing-for-windows-phone/

> As Microsoft acknowledged in the past, the version of Internet
>   Explorer found on mobile devices is similar but not identical to the
>   desktop browser version. There are a few key features that are not
>   available on Windows Phone: HTML5 touch drag-and-drop support (demo).
>   Videos which use the Encrypted Media Extension will not play on
>   Windows Phone. CSS Touch Views other than overflow:scroll CSS3
>   hyphenation is also not available These are all rather minor features
>   but you still need to know about the rendering differences and take
>   these into account.